# how to use curl to verify if a site's certificate has been revoked?

Tags: linux, certificate, curl

To check if the certificate for google.com has been revoked, I tried the following command:

```
curl https://www.google.com --cacert GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem --crlfile gtglobal.pem -v
```

, but I got the dreaded "SSL certificate problem" error:

```
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 81.24.29.91... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* successfully load CRL file:
*   CRLfile: gtglobal.pem
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

I guess this error is not correct, since Google should have a valid certificate.

Do you know how I could issue a curl command that does this correctly?

**More details**

If you're wondering why I used those specific files (GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem and gtglobal.pem) in the curl command, this is how I proceeded:

- I first looked at what CA issued the certificate for https://www.google.com. Turns out it is GeoTrust Global CA;
- I downloaded the GeoTrust Global CA root certificate from [here](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem) (this is the GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem file);
- I downloaded the corresponding CRL (certificate revocation list) from [here](http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl) (this is the gtglobal.pem file).

Comment: Seems to me like it already works? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @mtak - Considering the verification failed it seems the author is asking the reason why the certificate failed to verify, the certificate should have been verified, considering the current Google certificate has not been revoked.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that the question is a bit unclear. I will edit it. @Ramhound that is correct :)

Comment: I don't understand in principle why you would be connecting to https://www.google.com to confirm whether a certificate (which you already received during the TLS handshake) is present or not on a CRL (which you have already downloaded).  Shouldn't you do that on your own computer?  What if https://www.google.com was actually a MITM?

Comment: Here is an example of manually checking if a cert. is on a CRL once both the cert. and CRL are in local memory --- https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl%2dcookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html#checking-crl-revocation

Comment: It seems to me that thorough verification currently requires something like this: (1) Include a request for OCSP stapling in the original TSL handshake, (2) if the OCSP stapling is honored, then validate the sig, else goto 3, (3) issue an OCSP request to the approriate OCSP server, if an OCSP response is received in return then verify the sig., else goto 4 (4) request the appropriate CRL list, if the CRL lists is received ensure check sig then check list for presence of cert., else goto 5 (5) verify failed, decide whether to stop communication or continue un-safely.

Answer (score 20):

Apparently, you cannot just verify a site with a single simple request. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244084/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-certificate-has-been-revoked?lq=1 and older related questions on stackoverflow.

curl did not work with *Certificate Revocation Lists* for me either, neither on Windows, nor on Linux. Why should you use **curl**? **Openssl** seems more appropriate:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443
```

We get

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
```

Then we can inspect some certificate:

```
curl http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt | openssl x509 -inform der -text
```

`grep crl` in the output of the above command. The interesting parts are:

```
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:
            URI:http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl

        Authority Information Access:
            OCSP - URI:http://gtglobal-ocsp.geotrust.com
```

Now we can manually inspect crl:

```
curl http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl | openssl crl -inform der -text
curl http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl | openssl crl -inform der -text
```

Now we see a list of revoked certificates. IMHO, using curl is not enough, another program is required to check certificates. By doing a simple

```
strace curl https://www.google.com   -v
```

we see that curl is not checking revocations (not even connecting to the relevant places). It just says

```
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=www.google.com
*        start date: 2014-04-09 11:40:11 GMT
*        expire date: 2014-07-08 00:00:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: www.google.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
```

Comment: Why do you say curl can't do this? The curl manpage specifies the '--crlfile' option which exists exactly for this purpose. Also, curl is compiled with openssl and uses it for its crypto-related operations (including certificates) - it's just not working for me, trying to find out why :)

Answer (score 6):

curl since 7.41.0 has a `--cert-status` option, but it does not work for me:

```
$ curl --cert-status https://www.google.com
curl: (91) No OCSP response received
```

It appears maybe it only works if the server is configured with OCSP stapling, and it does not cause curl to make its own OCSP request.

I had better success using openssl with the steps at https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_Manually_Verify_a_certificate_against_an_OCSP.html

Fetch the cert:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 2>&1 < /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > /tmp/google.pem
```

Output the cert's OCSP URI:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in /tmp/google.pem 
http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1o1
```

Build a /tmp/chain.pem from the certs 1-n output by:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -showcerts 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

Copy each cert into the chain.pem file, including -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- and everything in between. Do not include the 0th cert since that's in the google.pem file.

Make the OCSP request:

```
openssl ocsp -issuer /tmp/chain.pem -cert /tmp/google.pem -text -url http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1o1
...
Response verify OK
/tmp/google.pem: good
    This Update: Mar 24 12:40:59 2020 GMT
    Next Update: Mar 31 12:40:59 2020 GMT
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is a pretty common problem on Windows, as [this question on stackoverflow shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/php-curl-https-causing-exception-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cer). I am specifically referring to the answer by user Артур Курицын, which I quote here for your convenience:

> It's a pretty common problem in Windows. You need just to set
>   `cacert.pem` to `curl.cainfo`.
>
> Since PHP 5.3.7 you could do:
>
> 1. download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it somewhere.
> 2. update `php.ini` -- add curl.cainfo = "PATH_TO/cacert.pem"
>
> Otherwise you will need to do the following for every cURL resource:
>
> ```
> curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PATH_TO/cacert.pem");
> ```

Also, [this article](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) might also be useful.

Comment: From what I know, the command-line option '--cacert' (which I used) is the equivalent of setting the CURLOPT_CAINFO option in libcurl, so I don't think this is the problem in my case (also, I'm using Linux)

Comment: Not exactly the answer to the question, still very useful information!

Answer (score 2):

One way I found working is similar to others already exposed, only it sends the output to `dev/null` and it is relatively quick to use.

`curl -L -v -s https://www.google.de 1>/dev/null`

```
# curl -L -v -s https://www.google.de 1>/dev/null
* About to connect() to www.google.de port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 216.58.208.35...
* Connected to www.google.de (216.58.208.35) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=www.google.de,O=Google LLC,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Okt 23 16:53:00 2018 GMT
*   expire date: Jan 15 16:53:00 2019 GMT
*   common name: www.google.de
*   issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G3,O=Google Trust Services,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www.google.de
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2018 15:36:17 GMT
< Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
< Server: gws
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2018-11-12-15; expires=Wed, 12-Dec-2018 15:36:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de
< Set-Cookie: NID=146=4SDchvTa39-4IskdXfZpgjtm2ym5zzvHVx8g0v39Q1fiOzk26NQl1TGkFMllh_pg8bFWr6x4jG3ODYDWrkn6TXmd0Ewp4DC_N3p1NPlWqdBUfwFR_PTHIXRi8RuTxdA54w9Zr0uNyhN__5xjUdrCLZTLujNEQ2MV9EVwnmxux6o; expires=Tue, 14-May-2019 15:36:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de; HttpOnly
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{ [data not shown]
* Connection #0 to host www.google.de left intact
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to tell us anything about whether the site's certificate has been revoked. Indeed, as per the documentation, `curl` on Unix doesn't check (unless you specifically compile it with an SSL library which automatically does this for you).